# how to update chart in python each second

Tags: python, charts, live

I am trying to update a time series data every second by using matplotlib.animation. This will be used for data acquisition from multiple channels. However, when I use the  animation in the update() function, the interval time is not achieved (the functions loops faster). Please help me clarify how to call the update function in a more proper way. Thanks.

- Most examples show calling the update() from outside the function. However, in this case, updating many channels at once becomes a problem.

  ```
  def update(self,start):
      x = np.random.normal(size=1)
      y = np.random.normal(size=1)
      deneme=self.graphicsView.plot(x,y,pen=None,symbol='+')
      time.sleep(0.2)
      animation.FuncAnimation(self.graphicsView,ui.update(),interval =1000)
  ```

Comment: Maybe use time.sleep(1) instead of time.sleep(0.2)

Comment: Unfortunately, time.sleep(x) is not really preffered in this case, because it will also keep all other processes on hold. Therefore, I tried calling the update function with threading.Timer (in this case probably time.sleep(x) will not mess up the other processes). However,  I could not get it repeatedly running (at each second).

Comment: You could try the datetime module and every time the second changes you could call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
from datetime import time
second = datetime.now().strftime("%S")
while True:
    do some things your code should do (no time.sleep in there)
    second_before = datetime.now().strftime("%S")
    if second != second_before:
        second = second_before
        call the function
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. is it possible to use something else instead of while True, it will keep the system busy I would guess?

Comment: Maybe setting a variable true after every iteration of other code and then setting it false at the end of this code

Answer (score 0):

I have found one method as follows. It seems to work fine by using thrading.Timer. Now, I am trying to make sure that the intervals are precise by checking process durations.

```
    def callfunc(self,val):
         process_delta=time.time()-val
         t=threading.Timer(1-process_delta,Ui_Dialog.update,args=(self,))
         t.daemon=True
         t.start()

    def update(self):
        process_start=time.time()
        value1=[]
        deltatime1=[]
        deltatime1.append(time.time()-start)
        y = np.random.normal(size=1)

        deneme=self.graphicsView.plot(deltatime1,y,pen=None,symbol='+')
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

        self.callfunc(process_start)

     start=time.time()   
     ui.callfunc(0)
```